# Adding a garage - do I need a cement foundation or is stone sufficient?

Tags: garage, foundation

I am planning to add a 12ft x 24ft single-car garage to my property to house my 1965 full-size Buick and stuff like bikes, lawn tools, etc.

I live in Delaware (Mid-Atlantic USA) and the most cost-effective option seems to be buying a prefab (or semi-prefab) structure to be delivered from one of the "Amish" builders near Lancaster, PA.  (I use "Amish" in quotes because it's unclear to me whether these companies actually employ sect members or whether it's being used more like a regional appellation.)

Anyway.

The biggest question I have left to answer is about the pad.  The places I have quotes from offer site prep services that involve a foundation using 4" of stone and a wood floor at a cost of just under $2,000.

If I want concrete I will have to work with a local contractor.  I'm still waiting on firm estimates but I was given a ballpark figure of $7,000 when I started making calls.

If this was just a garden shed I would take the stone option in the blink an eye.  But for a full-blown garage that will cost close to $15,000 and be occupied by a 2 ton vehicle 95% of the time, I have some doubts.  But at the same time, I don't want to spend an extra $5,000+ just because my mental conception of a garage includes a concrete floor.

Would stone hold up over time in this application?  Would the choice of foundation material impact my property value at resale?  Are there tools or sources that would help me make an informed choice here?

My Google-fu is usually pretty good but in this case I haven't had much luck finding resources to help me make an informed decision.  Advice and direction to resources would be greatly appreciated.

Two other points in case they're relevant:  My town has adopted the 2021 IEC rules, and I need to have some driveway and walkway work done at the same time anyway (not included in the $5K estimate).

Comment: What does your county or town in DE require?  I'm relatively close by (Talbot Co, MD) and for my garage they required a full footing (30" down?), block foundation wall, and a 4" concrete pad

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions of local code are explicitly [off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (oddly listed in the "on topic" section of help).

Comment: Well, OP originally asked about crushed stone with wood overlay vs concrete.  I'm the one that mentioned possible code requirements.

Comment: Am I reading correctly that someone suggested a wood floor in an _automobile garage_? Not something I've seen in anything designed for modern cars other than showrooms and museums where the vehicles are rarely moved...

Comment: OP said "4" of stone and a wood floor".

Comment: In my head, gravel is not the way to go even at that price delta but I'm looking for facts & advice which would support that notion to rule out assumptive thinking on my part.

If someone wants to point out something relevant within IEC 2021 I wouldn't object, but that's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: @keshlam this is for a classic car which would maybe come out once a week during good weather.  Honestly, it's that reduced frequency of use that's the only thing that makes me think the cheaper option might be okay -- but then there's the resale value question.

Comment: I wouldn't spend $15k on a building intended only to store one particular car. For that you can buy a car tent for $300.   For the extra money for a concrete floor you, or future owners, can use it as an actual daily garage, workshop, painting room,  gym, storage, and all kinds of temporary uses.

Comment: @jay613 I got a $300 car tent in 2020 and the wind has torn the top off of it twice, flipped it over into the neighbor's yard once, bent two legs in half, and shaken every fastener out of it.  So I've been there and done that.

Comment: Having parked cars on a wooden plank floor in a barn, (it was definitely not a garage, but we'd typically find some space for the winter)  I'd have zero concerns about a wood floor  for daily  car use if properly sized and supported for the purpose. That one was from the late 1800s and built to take loaded haywagons, cows, horses, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Foundations depend on your local ground conditions.**  Sand or clay, hard rock or gravel, sloping or flat, wet or dry, earthquake or flood.

Without knowing your site we can't really comment, except to say that an understanding of your ground conditions (plus local code) will give you some steer on what might be suitable for your site.

Since geology can change from one street to the next, some investigation of the ground at your site, plus asking around locally what is recommended or required by code may give you some idea what your options are for the locality.  If there is a geological map available for your area that may also offer some clues.